# JNDI port configuration for JBoss eap 6.4

Tags: jboss, jndi, communicationexception

We are migrating an application from JBoss AS 4.2 to JBoss eap 6.4. While deploying the application getting the below exception.

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:10099 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:10099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:10099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1562)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:634)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
```

The connection to localhost:10099 is failed. When I have checked in the jboss-service.xml file of AS 4.2 the configuration for this port is present.

```
 <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.NamingService"
      name="jboss:service=Naming"
      xmbean-dd="resource:xmdesc/NamingService-xmbean.xml">
      <!-- The call by value mode. true if all lookups are unmarshalled using
         the caller's TCL, false if in VM lookups return the value by reference.
      -->
      <attribute name="CallByValue">false</attribute>
      <!-- The listening port for the bootstrap JNP service. Set this to -1
         to run the NamingService without the JNP invoker listening port.
      -->
      <attribute name="Port">10099</attribute>
```

Can anyone please tell me where can we do the similar configuration in EAP 6. Tried adding in socket-binding-group in standalone.xml but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the boot.log to see what the value of jboss.bind.address is.
- There should be a line similar to:
  DEBUG [ServerInfo]     jboss.bind.address: 127.0.0.1
- Telnet to the server on the JNDI port to confirm there is a service      listening:1.telnet HOSTNAME/IP JNDI_PORT 2. JNDI by default would be on port 1099
- Check the firewall rules at the host machine and make sure ports  10099 are opened in order for twiddle to work.